# De Moivre's formula to solve $\cos$ equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Use De Moivre’s formula to show that
$$
\cos\left(x\right) + \cos\left(3x\right) = 2\cos\left(x\right)\cos\left(2x\right)
$$

$$
\mbox{Show also that}\quad
\cos^{5}\left(x\right) = \frac{1}{16}\,\cos\left(5x\right) + \frac{5}{16}\,\cos\left(3x\right) + \frac{5}{8}\,\cos\left(x\right)
$$
Hence solve the equation $\cos\left(5x\right) = 16\cos^{5}\left(x\right)$ completely. 
Express your answers as rational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: Lauren - We encourage users to accept an answer to a question they've asked if they find it to be helpful. While you can upvote as many answers as you find helpful, you can accept only one answer. To accept an answer, just click on the grey $\large \checkmark$ to the left of the answer you'd like to accept. It turns green when you click on it. And you receive two reputation points each time you accept one answer to a question you've asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me first show you another problem using DeMoivre's formula, to give you the idea of how to do the first two parts. Namely, I will show that $$\cos(4x)=8\cos^4x-8\cos^2x+1,$$ using only DeMoivre's formula and the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2x=1-\cos^2x$.

First off, we know that $$\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x)=(\cos x+i\sin x)^4,$$ and by expanding the right-hand side, we have $$\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x)=\cos^4x+4i\cos^3x\sin x-6\cos^2x\sin^2x-4i\cos x\sin^3x+\sin^4x.$$ Gathering our real and imaginary terms gives us $$\cos(4x)+i\sin(4x)=\cos^4x-6\cos^2x\sin^2x+\sin^4x+i(4\cos^3x\sin x-4\cos x\sin^3x),$$ so, remembering that sine and cosine are *real-valued functions on the reals*, we have that $$\cos(4x)=\cos^4x-6\cos^2x\sin^2x+\sin^4x.$$ At that point, we can rewrite as $$\cos(4x)=\cos^4x-6\cos^2x\sin^2x+(\sin^2x)^2,$$ which means that $$\cos(4x)=\cos^4x-6\cos^2x(1-\cos^2x)+(1-\cos^2x)^2,$$ whence expanding and collecting like terms gives us $$\cos(4x)=8\cos^4x-8\cos^2x+1,$$ as desired.

---

Now, once we've proved that $$\cos(x)+\cos(3x)=2\cos(x)\cos(2x)\tag{$\heartsuit$}$$ and that $$\cos^5(x) = \frac1{16}\cos(5x) + \frac5{16}\cos(3x) + \frac58\cos(x),\tag{$\diamondsuit$}$$ let us assume that $$\cos(5x)=16\cos^5(x).\tag{$\spadesuit$}$$ By $(\spadesuit)$ and $(\diamondsuit),$ we can conclude that $$0=\cos(3x)+2\cos(x).$$ (Do you see how?) By $(\heartsuit),$ it then follows that $$0=2\cos(x)\cos(2x)+\cos(x)\\0=\cos(x)\bigl(2\cos(2x)+1\bigr).$$ (Do you see how?) Thus, we have $$\cos(x)=0$$ or $$\cos(2x)=-\frac12,$$ which I leave to you to solve.

Comment: Love the suites for tags; but +1 on the math and the exposition!  Happy Thanksgiving!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:
$$ (\cos x + i \sin x)^n = \cos nx + i \sin nx $$

Comment: this was my starting point but seeing as sin isnt included i have no idea where to start?

Comment: Real and imaginary parts!

Answer (score 1):

@Lauren, the approach comes down to the fact that $Re[(\text{cos}(x)+i\cdot \text{sin}(x))^3] = \text{cos}(3x)$.

So, $$\text{cos}(3x) \\ = \text{cos}^3(x) + 3\text{cos}(x)\cdot (i^2\cdot \text{sin}^2(x)) \\ = \text{cos}(x)\cdot (\text{cos}^2(x) - 3\text{sin}^2(x)) \\ = \text{cos}(x)\cdot (1-2\text{sin}^2(x)+ \text{cos}(2x)-1) \\ = \text{cos}(x)\cdot (2\text{cos}(2x) - 1) = \text{cos}(3x).$$

This proves part 1. Then the next part follows from the fact that $\text{cos}(3x) = -2\text{cos}(x)$. Why? I'll leave this as an exercise.